# Postgres - range for 'time without time zone' and exclude constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
create table booking (
     identifier      integer                not null primary key,
     room            uuid                   not null,
     start_time      time without time zone not null,
     end_time        time without time zone not null
);
```

I want to create an `exclude constraint` to enforce that there are no overlapping appointments for the same room.

I tried the following:

```
alter table booking add constraint overlapping_times
exclude using gist
(
     cast(room as text) with =,
     period(start_time, end_time) with &&)
);
```

This has two problems:

- Casting `room` to `text` is not enough, it gives: `ERROR:  data type text has no default operator class for access method "gist"`. I know in v10 there is `btree_gist`, but I am using v9.5 and v9.6, so I have to manually cast the `uuid` to a `text` afaik.
- `period(...)` is wrong, but I have no idea how to construct a range of `time without time zone` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After [installing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/btree-gist.html), you can do the following:

```
create type timerange as range (subtype = time);

alter table booking add constraint overlapping_times
exclude using gist
(
     (room::text) with =,
     timerange(start_time, end_time) with &&
);
```

If you want an expression in the constraint you need to put that into parentheses. So either `(room::text)` or `(cast(room  as text))`

Comment: Thank you, this works! In v10, you can remove that cast, as `btree_gist` supports `uuid` type.

Comment: I did not realize you could construct custom ranges. That's cool!